# Install Gitorious -- Ubuntu server 11.04 -- Repository_Base_Path error

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, git

I followed this tutorial on installing gitorious http://coding-journal.com/installing-gitorious-on-ubuntu-11-04/ .  I have never install ruby on rails or gitorious so my knowledge is new.

I am getting an error after browsing to the domain that I am using.  The error reads Syntax error line 3 col 22; repository_base_path: "/var/www/gitorious/repositories""

[config/gitorious.yml]

```
production:
    repository_base_path: "/var/www/gitorious/repositories"
    gitorious_client_port: 80
    gitorious_host:  git.mypressbox.biz
    archive_cache_dir:  /var/www/gitorious/tarballs
    archive_work_dir:  /tmp/tarballs-work
    hide_http_clone_urls:  true
    is_gitorious_dot_org:  false
```

I dont know what to change. Running gem -v returns 1.8.11 .  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about removing tabs? I was having similar problem than I found [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/gitorious@googlegroups.com/msg01038.html) and solved:

> "I suspect this is a YAML parser error; you should make sure you use
>   the same indentation throughout the file (spaces vs tabs, number of
>   spaces etc.). Your editor probably has a switch for displaying
>   spaces/tabs, this should be of help..."